# JPanel to JFrame - moving the panel class to the frame GUI

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame

How do I get the Panel into the Frame. I've tried for hours and just don't get it.

I tried `JPanel panel = new TopPanel();` but It just will not call the Frame. Our teacher taught this to us a week ago for the beginner class and ever since this, I've been confused.

Thanks for helping in advance and please explain.

Frame:

```
public class CourseGUI extends JFrame {
    public CourseGUI()
    {

        super("CourseGUI Frame");


        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);

        topPanel.setPreferredSize(d);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(800,600);
        //JPanel tp = new TopPanel();
        //this.add(tp.BorderLayout.North);

        JPanel panel = new TopPanel();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CourseGUI();
    }

}
```

Panel (Suppose to be on the top)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    public TopPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(Crse);

    }
}
```

Comment: you have two panels in your code but you have added only the first one to frame; you have to add the second panel which actually has the label; add it to the frame like: this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Comment: Here, the code should not be extending either frame or panel, but simply using an instance of each.  Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TopPanel class you just add the lable into another JPanel object panel, and this panel is not added into TopPanel. I made a little change in your TopPanel class. (You can change the layout if needed )

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;


 public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

     public TopPanel() {

         JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
         Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(Crse);

     }
 }
```

use this TopPanel in CourseGui

```
  JPanel topPanel = new TopPanel();
```

Please try accept if it worked

You can alsoe use

```
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
    Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    topPanel.add(Crse);
```

Comment: Why extend panel here?

Comment: After extending JPanel, TopPanel itself a JPanel (Inheritance). You can use TopPanel as JPanel as all of JPanel's properties available in TopPanel. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: My point is [prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: After all of this, I still don't get it. I'm getting the same thing everyone is telling me to do, I do it BUT I still get a blank CourseGUI :C